# Python in Power BI - Show column names instead of numbers in matplotlib.pyplot.matshow

Tags: python, powerbi

I have a dataset similar to the below, in Power BI:

```
last_updated    product     price
01-01-2019      Cycle       1000
02-01-2019      Cycle       1010
01-01-2019      Helmet      200
02-01-2019      Helmet      190
```

Basically, I wanted to dynamically let the user choose some products from the filters, and I'd get Python to pivot the data and plot a correlation matrix.

It's only my second day with Python, but I have managed to write the following code.

```
dataset = dataset.pivot(
    index = 'last_updated',
    columns = 'product',
    values = 'price'
)

matplotlib.pyplot.matshow(dataset.corr('pearson'))

matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

It works as expected, but it shows 0, 1, 2, etc., instead of Cycle, Helmet,...

How can I set the tick labels dynamically to the column names?

I see some examples use set_xticklabels(), but I am not able to figure out how to use it to set a literal string, let alone dynamic column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this...

```
import seaborn as sns

dataset = dataset.pivot(
    index = 'last_updated',
    columns = 'symbol',
    values = 'cumulative_return'
)

corr = dataset.corr('pearson')
sns.heatmap(corr, annot=True, xticklabels=corr.columns, yticklabels=corr.columns)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```